# #gtsummary Odds Ratio in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

#gtsummary

Is there a way to make a table that has both Odds Ratio and adjusted Odds Ratio in gtsummary?

#RStats

I tried using tbl_reg however that has only adjusted OR and 95CI post regression. I want both in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I think these slides have the solution you're after: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/clinical-reporting-gtsummary-rmed/slides/#/tbl_merge-for-side-by-side-tables

You construct two tables: one with univariate results using `tbl_uvregression()` and a second with adjusted ORs using `tbl_regression()`. Then you combine them using `tbl_merge()`

[image]